Small proofs for large sums
Suppose we have $n$ public elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$, say elements of an elliptic curve $E$ (but maybe also $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ or $\mathbb{Z}_N^*$ with multiplication instead of sum), and an element $x$ assumed to be equal to the sum $x_1+\ldots+x_n$ (or product).
Can we verify the relation $x = x_1 + \ldots + x_n$ in less than $O(n)$ operations, and with a constant or high soundness?
Could the sum-check protocol be adapted to this use-case?

If elements $x_i$ are public (as stated), and $x$ is public too (we must know something about it anyway), what's wrong with computing $x_1 + \ldots + x_n$ then comparing to $x$?

I am wondering if it can be done faster. Something like an additive Merkle tree where we would only check $O(\log{n})$ additions. So we can think of a PCP type argument with the prover providing oracle access to $(x_1,\ldots,x_n)$, the value $x$, and a small proof $\pi=o(n)$ which verifies the relation in $o(n)$ accesses to the list. And preferably so that the soundness probability is high, preferably constant.

No, we can't verify the relation $x = x_1+\cdots+x_n$ in less than $\mathcal O(n)$ operations. This holds even with some of the work offloaded to an helper, unless we trust them.
Argument (without a helper): changing any $x_i$ or $x$ to another value breaks (or makes) the equality, therefore each of the $n$ inputs $x_i$ must be taken into account (in full to prove equality, at least in part to disprove it), thus cost is at least $\mathcal O(n)$.
We can offload the work to some helper and discount the work they perform. It's trivial if we trust that helper: we just rely on their say, and have constant work. It's also possible if we don't trust them, but in that case, we still need to perform $\mathcal O(n)$ operations ourselves.
Detailed argument (with an helper that we don't trust): Consider any public protocol attempting to allow what's asked. A rogue helper can randomly pick a $j\in\{1,\cdots,n\}$. If they try to make us believe in equality when it does not hold, they compute $x'_j=x+x_j-\sum x_j$, otherwise they pick any $x'_j\ne x_j$. Then they perform whatever the protocol requires as if the data set contained that $x'_j\ne x_j$ instead of $x_j$. The protocol can't allow us to detect their cheating unless it processes on our side the particular value $x_j$. Thus for constant residual probability $p$ of not detecting inequality, the protocol needs to process on our side as least $\lceil(1-p)\,n\rceil$ among the $n$ inputs $x_i$ (at least in part), thus cost is at least $\mathcal O(n)$ operations.
Note: I'm not claiming that my operations are group operations.

Offloading the work to a helper is implicit. Otherwise the question doesn't make much sense as the bare minimum is to read all the $O(n)$ inputs.
What I am asking is if there is a prover who can create a small proof which can be verified quickly, but the proof might have a large computation time, it might take even $O(n^2)$ to compute.
I feel like your arguments are too handwavy and not quite true. I had the same ones. But, in my defence, thigns like the PCP theorem exist, where you can prove a large sentence in only a constant number of queries, which is rather counterintuitive.

@Kojla: I stand by my impossibility statement, and I tried to make my argument more convincing in the rogue helper case, while you made the above comment, then after. But I admit I have read the question's "operations" as "cost" or "work", not "queries" or "group operations". If you consider that different, please detail the requirement.
